# Meteor, Iron Router, & Google Analytics Embed API

Tags: javascript, meteor, google-analytics, iron-router

After trying to authenticate Google API calls through Meteor's `accounts-google` package, I decided to try Analytics' Embed API to cut down on some complexity. I've been able to get individual dashboards working by loading the client library, authenticating, etc. on each template, but of course that's inefficient and filled with repetition.

What's the best way to load the Embed API library, authentication, and view selector once while allowing templates to detect them as they're loaded with Iron Router? Or am I simply forcing Meteor into an application it's not well-suited for?

I've added some sample code to give an idea of how things are structured now:

## /client/layout.html

```
<template name="layout">
    <header>
        <h1><a href="{{pathFor 'basic'}}">DDDashboard</a></h1>
    </header>
    <section id="admin">
        <div id="auth-button"></div> <!-- Outlet for Embed API's auth -->
        {{> view}} <!-- Outlet for the View template -->
    </section>
    <section id="main">
        {{> yield}} <!-- Outlet for each dashboard -->
    </section>
</template>
```

## /client/view.html

This template is used in a `Template.foo.rendered` to prevent the dashboard from loading until the Embed API view selector is fully instantiated.

```
<template name="view">
    <div id="view-selector"></div>
</template>
```

## /client/basic.html

Generic example of a dashboard—the Embed API relies on predefined elements to render into. More complex dashboards would have more `<div>` to contain other charts/info.

```
<template name="basic">
    <div id="data-container"></div> <!-- Outlet for the Embed API chart -->
</template>
```

## /lib/router.js

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});

Router.route('/', {
    name: 'basic'
});
```

## /client/lib/gapi.js

Loads the Google Embed API library at launch.

```
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fs){
  g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(f){this.q.push(f);}};
  js=d.createElement(s);fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
  fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics');};
}(window,document,'script'));
```

## /client/auth.js

```
gapi.analytics.ready(function(){
    gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
        container: 'auth-button',
        clientid: 'INSERT-CLIENTID'
    });         
});
```

## /client/view.js

Once the Embed API library is fully loaded, the view selector is created as a global variable so any chart or data objects can access it.

```
gapi.analytics.ready(function(){
    viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
        container: 'view-selector'
    });

    viewSelector.execute();
});
```

## /client/basic.js

Uses `Template.foo.rendered` to wait for the view selector to load; if it doesn't, the chart `div` remains empty. This dashboard contains one chart; others would contain many but more or less the same pattern.

```
Template.view.rendered = function(){
    gapi.analytics.ready(function(){
        var dataChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
            query: {
                metrics: 'ga:sessions',
                dimensions: 'ga:date',
                'start-date': '30daysAgo',
                'end-date': 'yesterday'
            },
            chart: {
                container: 'data-container',
                type: 'LINE',
                options: {
                    width: '100%'
                }
            }
        });

        viewSelector.on('change', function(ids){
            dataChart.set({query: {ids: ids}}).execute();
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: I don't see any reason why the Embed API wouldn't work with Meteor templates. Can you elaborate on what's currently not working with your existing code?

Comment: Sure. When I only have one template set up (e.g. basic), everything seems to load/update correctly. As soon as I try to add a second dashboard, both dashboards break. I'm somewhat our of my depth, but could it be how the Embed API objects emit and receive events and Meteor load order?

Comment: My assumption is it's a reference error. If view A creates the view selector in a local scope and view B needs to update when the selected view changes, view B somehow needs a reference to that JavaScript object or be notified by an event, or something like that.

Comment: Are you getting errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: No, no errors in the console. In the examples provided by the GA team, the view selector is always declared as a var within the dashboard closure; I made sure it's globally accessible(i.e. `var viewSelector = ...` v. `viewSelector = ...`). I'm hoping to play around with some more event listeners today.

Comment: Just found this in the docs: ["Fired any time the user selects a new view from the dropdown menus. It is also fired when the ViewSelector instance is first rendered and the default view is displayed."](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/component-reference#viewselector)

I think I'm going to try adding some triggers for the `emit` method and send some change events.

Comment: I think I've got it figured out. Since the ViewSelector object is only rendered once, the only the first Data and DataChart objects see a 'change' event and update accordingly. Any subsequent Data/DataChart objects in other templates don't see the event and update. When I call `dataChart.set({query: {ids: viewSelector.ids}}).execute();` in the console, everything's fine. The same call in the Meteor code results in 400 (Bad Request)"Required parameter: ids". @PhilipWalton , what's the simplest/preferred way to force that update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out to be pretty simple—just needed to add some Meteor sugar to get things behaving properly. Simple explanation: on a change from the viewSelector, set the current view as a Session variable; then add `Tracker.autorun()` blocks to grab updates and have the chart update itself. Also, be aggressive using `Template.view.created` callbacks to ensure objects load in the right order and aren't being rendered multiple times.

## /client/view.js

```
Template.view.created = function(){
    gapi.analytics.ready(function(){
        var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
            container: 'view-selector'
        });

        viewSelector.execute();

        viewSelector.on('change', function(ids){
            Session.set('currentView', ids);    
        });
    });
};
```

## /client/basic.js

```
Template.users.created = function(){
    gapi.analytics.ready(function(){
        dataChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
            query: {
                metrics: 'ga:users',
                dimensions: 'ga:date',
                'start-date': '30daysAgo',
                'end-date': 'yesterday'
            },
            chart: {
                container: 'data-container',
                type: 'LINE',
                options: {
                    width: '100%'
                }
            }
        });

        Tracker.autorun(function(){
            if(Session.get('currentView')){
                dataChart.set({query: {ids: Session.get('currentView')}}).execute();
            }
        });
    });
};
```

I'm sure there's room to improve with this pattern—wrapping each session variable into a `Tracker.autorun()` block on every dashboard seems a little superfluous, but keeping all the selectors and data objects locally-scoped is probably a but more secure and resistant to user tampering. Also works with date selection.

Comment: Would it be possible to have your code on codepen or something? Been losing so much time trying to figure out how to use embed-api on my meteor project. :(

Comment: Fwoof—it's been a while since I've worked on this guy. If I put the project on Github, would that work for you?

Comment: No promises, but keep an eye out :D

Comment: You would be a life-saver! :D

Comment: Ok, I had to start over from scratch (the original project was lost to some over-enthusiastic spring cleaning), but this appears to be working: https://github.com/mattpolicastro/ga-embed-meteor

Comment: Awesome, thank you @mattpolicastro for the trouble, I will have a look :)

Comment: Not a problem! Always happy to have an excuse to review and improve old work.